# Hindi English Machine translation using OpenNMT

Tags: machine-learning, classification, deep-learning, machine-translation

I am trying to perform machine translation using [this](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/).

I am using [this](https://github.com/karimkhanp/Seq2Seq/tree/master/data) dataset for training.

Result looks like this -

```
root@krm-datascience:/home/krm.khan/OpenNMT-py# python translate.py -model demo-model_acc_15.97_ppl_486.59_e1.pt -src data/src-test.txt -output pred.txt -replace_unk -verbose
Loading model

SENT 1: डेली हिन्दी न्यूज - बुंदेलखंड का प्रथम अन्तरजालीय स्थल
PRED 1: This .
PRED SCORE: -8.3647

SENT 2: मैं भारत से प्यार करता हूँ
PRED 2: This .
PRED SCORE: -8.1020

SENT 3: पाकिस्तानी सरकार के अनुसार इसी समय पाकिस्तान की नींव डाली गई थी ।
PRED 3: This .
PRED SCORE: -7.8469

SENT 4: ज़बूर जो कि दाउद को प्रदान की गयी
PRED 4: This .
PRED SCORE: -8.3363

SENT 5: प्रशासनिक विभाजन
PRED 5: India .
PRED SCORE: -6.6838

SENT 6: वे इस देश के प्रथम <unk> -LRB- अफ्रीकी <unk> -RRB-
PRED 6: This .
PRED SCORE: -8.2260

SENT 7: नेपाली विदेश <unk>
PRED 7: Hindi of India .
PRED SCORE: -11.5715
PRED AVG SCORE: -3.6957, PRED PPL: 40.2738
```

I could not understand the result. Is it correctly trained? Why result is so bad.